# Will the code be deleted when I close vscode-go:playground?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, go-playground

I accidentally clicked on "go run on go playground" when I was developing in vscode. Since it is a company code, I would like to know if the code will be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete the code yourself, but as mentioned in [this](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-dev/c/GrB7Qvu80vo) google groups thread, you can contact Russ Cox or security@golang.org and ask to delete the code.
But as long as you don't share the link, nobody should be able to see that code similar to YouTube's unlisted videos feature.